# Remote Server access/login problem

Tags: sql-server-2008

My OS is Windows Server 2008  Enterprise. I have installed SqlServer 2008. In network i want to access Other users Server,i have already enable remote access,**when i try to login show bellow error**

```
**Connection can not TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to TECHNO009.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'TECHNO009\Guest'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------**
```

Several times i try to connect as windows and sqlServer Authentication mode.But i failed,Other users also try to connect with my server they also failed and get the same message.

**Why error occur ,How to solve it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be for any number of reasons.

The first thing to do is follow [the link from the error message](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456).

These are the user actions recommended on it:

> If you are trying to connect using SQL Server Authentication, verify that SQL Server is configured in Mixed Authentication Mode.
>
> If you are trying to connect using SQL Server Authentication, verify that SQL Server login exists and that you have spelled it properly.
>
> If you are trying to connect using Windows Authentication, verify that you are properly logged into the correct domain.
>
> If your error indicates state 1, contact your SQL Server administrator.

Comment: @shamim - And what did you try? I don't know what you tried of the above and what didn't work, and I can't guess. You need to explain what you tried and what didn't work - you can edit the question and add details to it..